# Fastlane finish with error "The request could not be completed because: Unauthorized Access" in iOS

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, fastlane

I'm new in Fastlane and install it throw the official document. Now I want to create an app using Fastlane and try to run the basic command "**bundle exec fastlane create_app**" where "**create_app**" is a lane created in my Fastfile in my project directory.  After that, it is giving me the error: 
"**Unauthorized Access**"

I didn't understand why this is happening? I'm giving the output log below.

```
***@iOS-MAC-15 TryFastlane % bundle exec fastlane create_app
[✔]  
[10:27:24]: ------------------------------
[10:27:24]: --- Step: default_platform ---
[10:27:24]: ------------------------------
[10:27:24]: Driving the lane 'ios create_app' 
[10:27:24]: ---------------------
[10:27:24]: --- Step: produce ---
[10:27:24]: ---------------------
+----------------+--------------------------------+
|           Summary for produce 2.137.0           |
+----------------+--------------------------------+
| username       | ***                            |
| app_identifier | com.***.***                    |
| sku            | 1576643244                     |
| platform       | ios                            |
| language       | English                        |
| skip_itc       | false                          |
| skip_devcenter | false                          |
+----------------+--------------------------------+
Two-factor Authentication (6 digits code) is enabled for account '***'
More information about Two-factor Authentication: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915
If you're running this in a non-interactive session (e.g. server or CI)
check out https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/spaceship#2-step-verification
Environment variable `SPACESHIP_2FA_SMS_DEFAULT_PHONE_NUMBER` is set, automatically requesting 2FA token via SMS to that number
SPACESHIP_2FA_SMS_DEFAULT_PHONE_NUMBER = ***
Successfully requested text message to ***
Please enter the 6 digit code you received at ***:
999822
Requesting session...
+------------------+----------------+
|           Lane Context            |
+------------------+----------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM | ios            |
| PLATFORM_NAME    | ios            |
| LANE_NAME        | ios create_app |
+------------------+----------------+
[10:37:21]: Unauthorized Access
+------+------------------+-------------+
|           fastlane summary            |
+------+------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action           | Time (in s) |
+------+------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform | 0           |
|    | produce          | 597         |
+------+------------------+-------------+
[10:37:21]: fastlane finished with errors
Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane...
➡️  The request could not be completed because: Unauthorized Access
    https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15411 [closed] 21 
    3 weeks ago
➡️  Unauthorized Access when I use Fastlane pilot upload
    https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15125 [closed] 6 
    5 weeks ago
➡️  The request could not be completed because:Unauthorized Access
    https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/13923 [closed] 14 
    31 Jul 2019
and 15 more at: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/search?q=The%20request%20could%20not%20be%20completed%20because%3A%0A%09Unauthorized%20Access&type=Issues&utf8=✓
  You can ⌘ + double-click on links to open them directly in your browser.
[!] The request could not be completed because:
    Unauthorized Access
```

Appfile Details:

```
app_identifier "com.***.***" 
apple_id "***"
```

Fastfile Details:

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do

before_all do
    ENV["SPACESHIP_2FA_SMS_DEFAULT_PHONE_NUMBER"] = "***"
    ENV["FASTLANE_USER"] = "***"
    ENV["FASTLANE_PASSWORD"] = "***"
  end


# 1
  desc "Create app on Apple Developer and App Store Connect sites"
# 2
  lane :create_app do
# 3
​    produce
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solved the issue it is 2FA in CLI. First, remove the credential by 
**fastlane fastlane-credentials remove --username appleID**, Second, create apple application password on AppleID and use it as environment variable in fastlane "**FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD**" .finally, run the lane.
The **Fastfile** after added that variable looks like this.

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do

before_all do
    ENV["SPACESHIP_2FA_SMS_DEFAULT_PHONE_NUMBER"] = "***"
    ENV["FASTLANE_USER"] = "***"
    ENV["FASTLANE_PASSWORD"] = "***"
    ENV["FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD"] = "***"
  end


# 1
  desc "Create app on Apple Developer and App Store Connect sites"
# 2
  lane :create_app do
# 3
​    produce
  end
end
```

Comment: My answer was like 1) find your answer here 2) run `fastlane fastlane-credentials remove --username` 3) go again. For a single user with one computer, it's enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue by following steps:

1. Updating the fastlane to latest version (2.205.1 in my case)

   run this command to update fastlane : `bundle update fastlane`
2. signing in to my apple account from my browser.
3. Creating app specific password from https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage and adding it to fastFile like this:

default_platform(:ios)

```
platform :ios do
  ENV["FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD"] = "YOUR-APP-SPECIFIC_PASS"
  desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
  lane :beta do
    increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "Runner.xcodeproj")
    build_app(workspace: "Runner.xcworkspace", scheme: "Runner")
    upload_to_testflight(skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true)
    end
end
```

4. running : `fastlane ios beta` to upload my app to appStore

Comment: This also worked for me. I updated fastlane to current version: 2.206.1 then fastlane deployment worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the similar issue by doing 3 steps without storing password in plaintext:

1. If you have `fastlane` auth cached then open `Keychain Access` app, look up `deliver.*` internet password entry and delete it. That's your password cached by `fastlane`.
2. Go to https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage and generate new app-specific password. Name of the app label not important.
3. Open terminal, `cd` to your project folder and trigger `fastlane` build upload:

```
fastlane ios beta
```

- When `fastlane` prompts for username, enter your apple id.
- When `fastlane` prompts for `FASTLANE_PASSWORD`, enter your **app-specific password** you just generated!

Voila! Fastlane should be able to upload your build now!

*Update*

Unfortunately, it worked only one day and stopped working the next day :)